# How to get affected row count on WordPress query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, csv

This code is to use in WordPress plugin.

The following is my code I am using to insert data from CSV file to database:

```
$sql="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$fileurl."' INTO TABLE ".$table_name."
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (`first_name`,`last_name`, `email`, `mobile_phone`, `address_1`, `address_2`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `about_us` );
                ";
                $query = $wpdb->query($sql);
```

When I do this `var_dump($query);` it shows `int(0)`, and data is successfully inserted in table. My question is how can I get number of inserted rows?

Comment: whici database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very old question, I know, and perhaps this answer is trivially obvious, but posting in the hope it might be useful to someone who stumbled across it as I did.

In this particular case with LOAD DATA, one option might be to simply run an sql COUNT() before and after the LOAD DATA, and then take the difference:

```
$count_before = $wpdb->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name");
// LOAD DATA ...
$count_after = $wpdb->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name");
$new_rows = $count_after - $count_before;
```

I understand this may not work well if there is other simultaneous activity on the table; though you may be able to lock the table to prevent conflicting updates and to make the LOAD DATA even faster.  You might be able to get this with $wpdb->affected_rows and that's also worth checking.

No doubt since it's 2 years ago since you asked this, you have any number of other working solutions; hopefully this is useful to anyone googling for a solution here.

Answer (score 4):

Object `$wpdb` contains a lot of useful things. You can watch this by dump this object to see public properties.

One of them is what you search:

```
echo $wpdb->rows_affected;
```

Comment: If I look into the code `wp-includes/wp-db.php` `function query( $query )`, the attribute seems to be `rows_affected`.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query

Answer (score 3):

You can find the affected rows in your query using below.

```
$count = $wpdb->query($sql);
```

$count is your affected rows.

Comment: question is for wordpress code, and i am using mysql

Comment: @PriME check my edit. In your code, just var_dump is not required.

Comment: have you tested it ?

Comment: Did u tested it? @PriME

Comment: please read question properly, `$count = $wpdb->query($sql);`   in this code `$count` output `int(0)`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get this information using a `LOAD DATA` statement with `wpdb::query()`. It doesn't understand the statement, so doesn't automatically fetch the number of affected rows. You can't get it yourself, either, because the necessary `wpdb` class properties (`use_mysqli`, `dbh`) are not `public`.